# Audit on a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server

We have an app database on SQL Server 2014. After system went live, we find this weird thing one of the table columns keep reset to 0, we don't know at this point if it is a bug or who is messing up with intention.

Question, is there a way to audit the user changed this table and possibly the statement (update/delete) did this?

Thanks

Comment: [CDC](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2015/understanding-sql-server-change-data-capture-cdc/)

Comment: Use event or trace to track all the inserts/updates/deletes on that table. My bet however is a piece of broken (so not malicious) code: `update sometable set col=0` which should have read `update sometable set col=0 where id=?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO I believe, not unless you maintain the audit history in a table separately which may have the field like `user_modified`, `date_modified`, `source_of_modification` like from some application or direct command, etc.